# facebook like: href url vs. canonical url

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

for tracking purposes, I want that the URL, which appears on the facebook stream after an "like-action", is slightly different from the URL the user actually liked.

**Example:**
I use `<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/test.html">` in my head section to tell facebook to which URL a like-action on this website refers to.

Further down on the website I have `<fb:like href="http://example.com/test.html?param=144141">` with the same URL, just with an additional parameter.

My intention: If someone clicks on the like button, facebook puts him to the "group who like http://example.com/test.html" in order to appear next the like button. But when another user sees his like-action on the facebook stream and clicks on it, he should be redirected to http://example.com/test.html?param=144141.

The problem is that this doesn't work, because the canonical declaration in the head section kind of overwrites the href attribute of my `<fb:like>` tag. Anyone knows how to solve this problem or does it simply not work?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't do exactly what you have requested, but you can still add an arbitrary tracking parameter (especially useful for analytics purposes). Facebook [recently added a `ref` parameter](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/397) to the `fb:like` element for this purpose. It's up to you to decide how you want to stuff various bits of information into that single parameter and then parse `fb_ref` whenever it's included in an incoming URLs.

**Example**

Place the following element on your HTML page:

```
<fb:like href="http://example.com/test.html" ref="144141"></fb:like>
```

Users clicking the link from Facebook should be directed to:

```
http://example.com/test.html?fb_ref=144141&fb_source=home_multiline
```

**Documentation**

- ["Adding More Features to the Like Button" blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/397)
- [fb:like button documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like)

Comment: Awesome. That's enough for my purposes. Thank you!

Comment: is there a way to do this if i am using HTML5 instead XFBML?

Comment: @MartinSchaer, you would probably add the data-ref attribute to your div, a bit like `<div class="fb-like" data-ref="144141"></div>`.

Comment: @PCheese pls, see my answer...I have the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16059918/facebook-like-button-ignore-url-parameters/16060616?noredirect=1#comment22920850_16060616