# Need Advice: Facebook Like Button to like a subsite 

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

i'm struggling around for days now ...this is the scenario:

a user can upload a pic and add some text on the site. After that, he/she gets a link that leads to his created content. I want the user not only to share his content with the link, but also on facebook with specified image and text. Tried this with open graph tags, but it is bad changing those tags dynamicly before liking because fb caches that info and does not recognize specific changes ... but correct me if i'm wrong ...

The problem seems to be, that when the user clicks on the like button, the content to share is not the actual site, but the subsite with its content ...

How would you do this?
Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I would drop the Open Graph api (which was not made for this) and go with the javascript sdk. That way you can manually post to the users wall, with whatever link and image you want and also customize the message.

Comment: thanks for that ... i've looked throu the fbjs sdk but did not find something for sharing a link ... do you know how this is made or rather what i have to look for ...

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.ui/ Her you will find an example. FBJS has been deprecated by Facebook. Javascript SDK is the new SDK: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: @Elad Lachmi: that's exactly what i did ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doing it with the fbjs sdk was the right hint ... now it works perfektly and individual ...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

[facebook like: href url vs. canonical url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149455/facebook-like-href-url-vs-canonical-url)