# Add parameter to URL with Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, parameters, url-parameters

I have a web page with a jQuery lightbox that opens automatically on page load. In the lightbox I have implemented the Facebook Like button (this is a 2 click solution for Facebook Like button in email).  Now, when a Facebook user visits my web page by clicking on the "Liked" URL on Facebook I want to turn off the lightbox.  I don't want to have to create two different pages (one with lightbox turned on and another turned off) and I think I can avoid this by adding a parameter to the URL with Javascript then turn the lightbox on/off based on that parameter.  Is this a safe way to do this?  How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get URL params with this JS function that I [found here](http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/):

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
```

Then *add use `?lightbox=1` e.g `www.example.com?lightbox=1` and read it with the above function:

```
if(getUrlVars()["lightbox"]=="1"){
    //...
}
```

*to add parameters you can either:

- Change the a link href attribute `element.href = "http://www.newURL.com?param=1";` and wait for the user to click them
- Redirect to the new location `window.location.href = "http://www.newURL.com?param=1";`

Comment: This seems to go in an infinite loop. :-(

Comment: When you said add to the link ?lightbox=1 do you mean var url = "www.example.com?lightbox=1";

Comment: The function only grabs the url param but not append to it ?lighbox=1. I'm trying to append to the url so that I can turn the lighbox on and off based on the the new param.

Comment: @user1312079 I updated the question to suggest two options on how to append params to the url

Comment: Got it to work by appending param to facebook iframe like button.

<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fexample.html?lightbox=1"></iframe>

With XFBML facebook does not accept param ?lightbox=1.

<fb:like href="http://www.example.com/example.html?lightbox=1" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>

Any ideas?

Comment: Found what I was looking for here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149455/facebook-like-href-url-vs-canonical-url

And here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the rough code you're after:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.location="http://example.com/index.php?noLightBox=1";
</script>
```

Then on index.php, you'd want something such as:

```
<?php 
function isset_or(&$check, $alternate = NULL) 
{ 
    return (isset($check)) ? (empty($check) ? $alternate : $check) : $alternate; 
} 

function getGETPOST($var) 
{ 
       return isset_or($_GET[$var],isset_or($_POST[$var],"Empty")); 
} 
?>
```

Example:

```
if(getGETPOST('noLightBox') != 1) {
// Code to display the light box comes here.
}
// Else normal page code
```

Hope this was helpful!
Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php
& W3School's tutorials on PHP

Comment: Can you do this without server side scripting?  Thank you.

Comment: On the first page it is local client sidded JavaScirpt, if you want to not have the other end in PHP here's a way to do it in JavaScript. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961069/getting-value-get-or-post-variable-using-javascript
It's most tedious tho.